# BDD and table view data source

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, delegates, bdd

In my current project I do Behavior Driven Development.

The app has a table view. I have a `UITableViewController` subclass and a subclass on `NSObject` as the data source and the delegate of the table view.

The data source (and delegate) of the table view is set as a property to the table view controller and this sets it as the data source and delegate of the table view in `viewDidLoad`.

In TDD I would test if the table views data source and delegate is the same object set to the property of the table view controller. In addition I would test the data source. But in BDD my impression is that this is to much internal information within the spec.

In BDD I would rather test the contents of the table view. But this would mean that I have to set up in the test two objects under test at once. The table view controller and the delegate of the table view. This seems wrong because this makes the test again dependent from internal implementation.

I don't want to have the table view controller to define the data source of the table view because I want to reuse it for different table views in the same app.

Any ideas how this "should" be done in BDD?

Comment: Please explain your down vote! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BDD stands for Behaviour Driven Development. What this entails is thinking about and describing the behaviour 'before' you do the development. In this case you've done the development first so of course you are finding it hard to do BDD

Once you've already got your code and your trying to 'test' it, then your not doing BDD or TDD.

You could do a thought experiment with BDD by pretending you haven't written your view.  Then write a scenario that describes why you need this particular view (i.e. what business value does it give) and what you might do with it ...

Alternatively just write a unit test for the code you've written

Comment: Yes, you are completely right. It's hard for me because I do this kind of setup all the time and I already know how this "should" look like. But let's say I have such a test and it turns out that I need two real classes to setup the test. Is this good practice?

Comment: I can't say because I don't know what you are testing, why you are testing it, and how you are testing it. You might be better off making a seperate question with your code and your test.